# Merging multiple sorted ranges

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple ranges using std::merge repeatedly.  It says template argument deduction failed.  Could someone explain why this will not compile?  Is the problem the use of multiple packs?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator multi_merge (OutputIterator result) {return result;}

template <typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2, typename OutputIterator,
    typename... InputIterators1, typename... InputIterators2>
OutputIterator multi_merge (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterators1... firsts1, 
InputIterator1 last1, InputIterators1... lasts1,
InputIterator2 first2, InputIterators2... firsts2, InputIterator2 last2, 
InputIterators2... lasts2, OutputIterator result) {
    // incorrect algorithm deleted
    return multi_merge (firsts1..., lasts1..., firsts2..., lasts2..., result);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {3,4,6,1,2},  b = {6,8,9,2},  c = {6,7,4,5,2}, result;
    std::sort (a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort (b.begin(), b.end());
    std::sort (c.begin(), c.end());
    multi_merge (a.begin(), b.begin(), c.begin(), a.end(), b.end(), c.end(),
        std::back_inserter(result));
}
```

Also, I would like the argument to be in the order first1, last1, first2, last2, ..., instead but that is a minor thing.

Edit:  I realize my merging logic is wrong.  I think this is the way:  First merge [a1, b1), with [a2, b2), and then use the resulting merged range [merged1, merged2) and merge with [a3, b3), and so forth.  So the compiling error is no longer the issue.  Another idea is to copy all the elements from each range into a container and then sort that (if that makes any sense even), but that is not the solution I seek though, but I will accept it if that is the only way.

Comment: When you get a compiler error, please include it in the question. Preferably with copy/paste.

Comment: The variadic template parameter should be the last. You may group them with `std::tuple`.

Comment: It says template argument deduction failed, but the above is a full example that anyone can use.

Comment: @Jarod42.  Can't there be a solution without tuple in the argument?  Ideally, multi_merge should be used exactly like std::merge but with extended arguments for the multiple ranges, right?

Comment: @prestokeys: You may also change the signature to `template <typename OutputIterator, typename ... InputIterators> OutputIterator multi_merge(OutputIterator, InputIterators...);`

Comment: I tried various orders, none of them compiled.  The ideal order I want, incidentally, is  first1, last1, first2, last2, ..., result, for what it's worth.

Comment: Note also that your current algo doesn't result in a sorted vector.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that just before you posted your comment.  And edited my post.  So this brings the whole problem back to square one.

Comment: Hard to use `[merged1, merged2)` with `back_inserter`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't have more than one variadic in each template.

How would you know where one starts and the other ends?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed the function signature from my opening post.  And now it is working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Container>
std::vector<typename Container::value_type> multi_merge (const Container& container) {
    return container;
}

template <typename Container1, typename Container2, typename... Containers>
std::vector<typename Container1::value_type> multi_merge (const Container1& container1,
const Container2& container2, const Containers&... containers) {
    std::vector<typename Container1::value_type> v;
    auto it = std::merge (container1.begin(), container1.end(), container2.begin(), 
        container2.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
    return multi_merge (v, containers...);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {3,4,6,1,2},  b = {6,8,9,2}, c = {6,7,4,5,2}, d = {3,2,4};
    std::array<int,6> e = {5,6,2,7,1,3};
    std::sort (a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort (b.begin(), b.end());
    std::sort (c.begin(), c.end());
    std::sort (d.begin(), d.end());
    std::sort (e.begin(), e.end());
    const std::vector<int> result = multi_merge (a, b, c, d, e);
    for (int x : result) std::cout << x << ' '; // 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 8 9
}
```

I still wonder how it would be done with the original signature in my opening post though, because that signature follows in the spirit of std::merge (using only iterators), and generalizes the output container with an output iterator.